# Is the 1st argument of an Objective C variadic function mandatory?

Tags: objective-c, function, variadic-functions

Here is an [example](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1405/_index.html) of a variadic function in Obj C.

```c
// This method takes an object and a variable number of args
- (void) appendObjects:(id) firstObject, ...;
```

Is it really mandatory to have the first argument as an Obj C object? If not, what should be the syntax?

EDIT: Thanks for your responses - the first argument does not need to be an `NSObject`, but what I meant to ask is: **Is it possible to do away with the first argument altogether?** *I probably did not frame the question well the first time around; sorry about that*

```c
- (void) appendObjects: ...;
```

The above declaration throws the following error: `Expected ';' after method prototype`

Comment: You mean the `(id)`? What type of objects you want to pass?

Comment: @emptystack: I want it to be `- (void) appendObjects: ...;` but the compiler throws this error: `Expected ; after method prototype`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't have to be anything really. There are two hidden arguments to every Objective-C method, `self`, and `_cmd` (in that order). `self` is self-explanatory (haha), but a lesser-known one is `_cmd`, which is simply the selector that was used to invoke the current method. This makes it possible to use variadic arguments with Objective-C methods seemingly without using an initial argument like you do with a standard variadic C function.

```
- (void) someMethod:...
{
    va_list va;

    va_start(va, _cmd);

    // process all args with va_arg

    va_end(va);
}
```

Then you can call the method like this:

```
 [someObj someMethod:1, 2, 3];
```

Comment: My compiler (LLVM 3.0) complains about the `someMethod:...` syntax, what gives?

Comment: Not sure... maybe a bug? It works for me, but I'm using an older version of GCC. There is no "Objective-C Standard" (in the sense that there is a C language standard) so perhaps this syntax has been dropped in LLVM.

Comment: Same here (GCC 4.2). Also: How would you know how many args you received when processing the va_list (for non nil-terminated input)

Comment: @weichsel: it depends, any value can mean "stop processing", for example, keep using `va_arg(va, int)` until you get a `-1`, or an `INT_MAX`, or whatever you want.

Comment: OK. I'd make that explicit (preferably in the first arg).

Comment: @dreamlax: Isn't ObjC a strict superset of C? Surprised that the syntax `- (void) someMethod:...` works with old gcc but errors out on LLVM, which is what I am using.

Answer (score 3):

The Objective-C way to implement variadic args is the same as in standard C. So you can pass in non-Objective-C object arguments.
Personally I'd use the first non-hidden arg to pass in the length of the following variadic list (for non-Objective-C objects - otherwise I'd use nil-termination)

```
- (void)appendIntegers:(NSInteger)count, ...
{
    va_list arguments;
    //the start of our variadic arguments is after the mandatory first argument    
    va_start(arguments, count);
    for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        //to add the non-object type variadic arg, wrap it in a NSNumber object
        [list addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:va_arg(arguments, NSInteger)]];
    }
    va_end(arguments);
    NSLog(@"%@", list);
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    list = [NSMutableArray array];
    [self appendIntegers:3 /* count */, 1, 2, 3];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn’t have to be an object. You can write a variadic function taking floats, for example:

```
- (void) doSomethingWithFloats: (float) float1, ...;
```

Comment: +1 @zoul: You are right - the first object can be any non-ObjC object. Further, is the first arg (NSObject or not) mandatory? Can it be avoided altogether?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. It seems to depend on the compiler, see dreamlax’s answer and the comments below it.