# Possible to use variadic arguments as first parameter of a method?

Tags: objective-c, variadic-functions

Typically, methods (and functions) that use variadic arguments seem to have it as the 2nd parameter like so:

```
- (void)setContentsWithFormat:(NSString *)formatString, ...;
```

Is it possible to declare this method so the variadic arguments are the first and sole parameter to this method? If so, what's the syntax for it?

I tried: `- (void)setContentsWithArguments:(...)` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't possible. The first parameter is effectively the reference point which tells the variadic functions how to access the additional parameters. Hence the `va_start` function takes the first method parameter (or, rather, the parameter just before the veridic) as its parameter:

```
- (void)doSomethingWithStrings:(NSString *)firstString, ...
{
    va_list vList;
    va_start(vList, firstString);
    ... blah blah
}
```

Comment: But Objective-C methods always have two implicit parameters in front, `self` and `_cmd`. So `va_start` could take `_cmd`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [GCC supported it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357912/is-the-1st-argument-of-an-objective-c-variadic-function-mandatory) with the syntax:

```
- (void)setContentsWithArguments:...
```

But LLVM does not.