# How to declare a block function with variadic arguments in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, variadic-functions

How to declare a block function with variadic arguments in Objective-C?

```
NSString *(^fn)(va_list) = ^(...) {  // ?

};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. A `va_list` argument is not the same as a `...` argument.
2. A variadic C function must have at least one named argument.

Here's an example that compiles:

```
NSString *(^fn)(NSString *format, ...) = ^NSString *(NSString *format, ...){
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, format);
    NSString *answer = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:ap];
    va_end(ap);
    return answer;
};
```

Comment: Is it possible to combine `_cmd` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7358326/10900045) but with blocks?

Comment: No. A block has no implicit arguments like `self` and `_cmd` that you can access by name.

Comment: The C function that implements a block does have one implicit argument (the pointer to the block), but you're right, the language does not provide a way to access this argument in the block.